# Updating an array field in firebase using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Im trying to update an array field of usernames in firebase using react.But for some reason my array is undefined.What im doing wrong?

```
const[saveusername,SetsaveUsername]=useState('')
const usernameRef=db.collection('chats')
const [usernameSnapshot]=useCollection(usernameRef)
const[usernameArray,SetusernameArray]=useState([])
console.log(usernameArray)



const SaveUsername=()=>{
   if(!!usernameSnapshot?.docs?.[0]?.data()?.usernames){
      SetusernameArray(usernameArray.concat(usernameSnapshot?.docs?.[0]?.data()?.usernames))
      console.log(usernameArray)
        db.collection('chats').doc(router.query.id).update({
            usernames:usernameArray
        })
   }
   else{
    db.collection('chats').doc(router.query.id).update({
        usernames:[{email:recipient?.email,username:saveusername}]
    })
   }    
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOsrH.png)

Comment: Which array is undefined? At what point in the code is it undefined?

Comment: at the start.This code is just not working :/

Comment: Ok. usernameArray seems to be defined and useState sets an empty array to it. For it to be undefined is odd unless there is something odd going on. What are you trying to achieve with SaveUsername?

Comment: This is a chat app so im trying to add an username to the person im chatting with by saving it in firebase as an array.Do you know any better way to do it?